# Which cloud region could have the fastest time for a docker image push?

Tags: image, docker, cloud

**TLDR**
How to know what region in the cloud nearest to docker hub?

**Full details**
From my localhost my network is super slow to push the docker image onto docker hub.

My workaround is to use a cloud machine to do that `docker image push` hopefully that the internet there would be faster.

So my question is which region on the cloud is nearest to docker hub for me to choose?

[My google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=which%20cloud%20region%20best%20to%20docker%20image%20push%20time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) results little helpful

p.s. I also asked on devops sister site [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/11238/19335)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from **John Humphreys - w00te** 's [answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/11241/19335) in DevOps the sister stackoverflow site

> From cloud instance, just go push to docker hub; you will be routed to the best location automatically.

Answer (score 3):

## Hostname of the `registry` server of `hub.docker.com`

If you mean in your question the public server `hub.docker.com`, then it's registry [has address](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/downloading-docker-images-from-docker-hub-without-using-docker) `registry-1.docker.io`

## `A-records` of `registry.docker.io`

You can find actual DNS `A-records` using `dig` or `nslookup`

```
nslookup -type=A registry.docker.io                                                                                                                           6.66 Dur  23:22:32 
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
registry.docker.io      canonical name = registry-1.docker.io.
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.206.192.146
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.87.94.70
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.55.198.220
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 54.152.200.115
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 54.164.50.37
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.2.169.2
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.202.253.107
Name:   registry-1.docker.io
Address: 52.201.142.14
```

```
 dig +short registry.docker.io A                                                                                                                              
registry-1.docker.io.
54.210.105.17
3.210.179.11
3.224.11.4
54.164.50.37
3.221.133.86
100.24.246.89
3.209.173.81
54.174.39.59
```

## `ipinfo` for geolocation

[There are some `CLI` tools](https://github.com/chubin/awesome-console-services) for IP-geolocation, let's use `ipinfo`

For example, `ipinfo` for it's nearest Cloudflare server:

```
curl ipinfo.io/1.1.1.1                                                                                                                                                  {
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "hostname": "one.one.one.one",
  "city": "Haymarket",
  "region": "New South Wales",
  "country": "AU",
  "loc": "-33.8661,151.2040",
  "org": "AS13335 Cloudflare, Inc.",
  "postal": "2000",
  "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

## Extract `city` and `hostname` using [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)

Since `ipinfo` returns answer in `JSON` format, we can parse it. `jq` is a convienient tool for such task.

```
curl -s ipinfo.io/54.210.105.17 | jq -r '{city:.city, host:.hostname}'
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-54-210-105-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
```

## Nearest city for all `registry` servers

Let's try to find nearest city for all resolved servers:

```
for addr in $(dig +short registry-1.docker.io A); do
  curl -s ipinfo.io/$addr | jq -r '{city:.city, host:.hostname}'; 
done
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-3-209-173-81.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-54-210-105-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-100-24-246-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-3-224-11-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-54-164-50-37.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-3-221-133-86.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-3-210-179-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
{
  "city": "Virginia Beach",
  "host": "ec2-54-174-39-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Comment: Super awesome details answer. Will definitely follow yours detail later soon.